# Sort out duplicates in one row but keep a specific one

Tags: c#, linq

What Im trying to do, is distinct (or group by) for one column, but then keeping the one in my List which has a value fo a second column.

What i have

```
Column1 Column 2 Column3 ...
   1   |  tada  | smth
   1   |        | wefih
   2   |  tada  | uitethgev
   3   |        | urifnvf

what i want
Column1 Column 2 Column3 ...
   1   |  tada  | smth
   2   |  tada  | uitethgev
   3   |        | urifnvf
```

As i only have one "3" i wanna keep it in my list. Same for the 2, but the 1 should only stay with a value in column2.

I wanna do this in a linq query. Each row is an Object with attributes that represent the columns.
Any clues on this? I know how to make it by using multiple lists and writing to each other with a method checking it. But i thought there could be a nice linq way to do this. Also keep in mind pls that i have more then just 3 columns.

Comment: Look into `GroupBy`

Comment: I think the group by is not an answer for my solution, cause im still missing the condition "when grouping always keep the one with value"

Comment: Yea seems like you were right and i just didnt know advanced group by, so thank you too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by `linq`, specially by `GroupBy` why not :

1 - i'm creating a `class` that simulate your demand :

```
public class TestClass
{
    public int Column1 { get; set; }
    public string Column2 { get; set; }
    public string Column3 { get; set; }
}
```

2 - i'm initializing a list of `TestClass` like a below:

```
List<TestClass> testClasses = new List<TestClass>
{
    new TestClass{Column1 = 1, Column2 = "tada", Column3 = "smth"},
    new TestClass{Column1 = 1, Column2 = "msa", Column3 = "msa1"},
    new TestClass{Column1 = 1, Column3 = "wefih"},
    new TestClass{Column1 = 2, Column2 = "tada", Column3 = "uitethgev"},
    new TestClass{Column1 = 3, Column3 = "urifnvf"},
};
```

3 - using `groupBy` to filter your list, by testing the `count` of grouped element is grater than or equal `2` :

> **if count >= 2** : take the first element that have a `column2` not empty
>
> **else** : take element without filtering

```
List<TestClass> groupedList = testClasses
    .GroupBy(x => x.Column1)
    .Select(y => y.Count() >= 2 ? y.First(z => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(z.Column2)) : y.First())
    .ToList();
```

> Result of 3 :

```
  Column1|Column 2| Column3 ...
  1      |  tada  | smth
  2      |  tada  | uitethgev
  3      |        | urifnvf
```

4 - if you need all not empty `column2`, if the `count` grater than `2`, try this code :

```
List<TestClass> groupedList = testClasses
    .GroupBy(x => x.Column1)
    .SelectMany(y => y.Count() >= 2 ? y.TakeWhile(z => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(z.Column2)) : y)
    .ToList();
```

> Result of 4 :

```
  Column1|Column 2| Column3 ...
  1      |  tada  | smth
  1      |  msa   | msa1
  2      |  tada  | uitethgev
  3      |        | urifnvf
```

i hope that will give you an answer

Comment: this one is really good. Thanks alot this helped me. your solution is pretty clean. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The following linq works :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Column1", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Column2", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Column3", typeof(string));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, "tada", "smth"});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, null, "wefih"});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, "tada", "uitethgev"});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 3, null, "erifnvf"});

            DataTable dt2 = dt.AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(x => x.Field<int>("Column1"))
                .Select(x => x.All(y => (y.Field<object>("Column2") == null)) ? x.First() : x.Where(y => y.Field<object>("Column2") != null).First())
                .CopyToDataTable();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well unfortunately it didnt work. It shows only only result.